# How can i use the result of InputBox for the directory of a query?

Tags: sql, excel, inputbox, vba

I'm trying to run a query in Excel based on an access file. The reason i want to do it by macro is the number of times with different files that i have to do the proceedure. I'm trying to use Inputbox to identify the name of the database i want to use but i can't get it to work as i constantly get errors about mismatch. Any help please?? Here is what i have made so far,

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim myValue As Variant

  Set myValue = Application.InputBox("Please type in the exact name of the source database")

  With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=ThisWorkbook.Path & " \ " & myValue.accdb;DefaultDir=ThisWorkbook.Path;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;" _
    )), Destination:=Range("$B$3")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "TRANSFORM Sum(Daily.RT_RENTAL_COUNT) AS SumOfRT_RENTAL_COUNT" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "SELECT Daily.[Full CN_CR_PARENT_NAME]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM Daily" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "GROUP BY Daily.[Full CN_CR_PARENT_NAME]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "PIVOT Daily.RT_CKOT_LOC_ID;" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" _
    )
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
     Set myValue = Application.InputBox("Please type in the exact name of the source database")
```

do

```
         myValue = Application.InputBox("Please type in the exact name of the source database")
```

InputBox returns a string, not an object, so you cannot use "set" with a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that but i get a mismatch error '13'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually. The problem was on the was i was trying to link the result of the inputbox to the file directory! This is how it worked. It might help others as well :)

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & myValue & "; DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:=Range("$B$3")).QueryTable
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "TRANSFORM Sum(Daily.RT_RENTAL_COUNT) AS SumOfRT_RENTAL_COUNT" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "SELECT Daily.[Full CN_CR_PARENT_NAME]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM Daily" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "GROUP BY Daily.[Full CN_CR_PARENT_NAME]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "PIVOT Daily.RT_CKOT_LOC_ID;" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" _
    )
```